# Should I dispose of the old font when changing the font of a control?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, dispose

C#, Windows Forms app.

We're re-skinning our application and I'm also changing the awful default font we used in the old one. So I thought I'd call the following function to change the font of all controls on a form when the form is loaded.

```
  internal static void SetFonts(Control control)
  {
    Font oldFont = control.Font;
    if (oldFont.Name != GlobalFontName)
    {
      string familyName = GlobalFontName;
      Font newFont = new System.Drawing.Font(familyName,
        oldFont.Size, oldFont.Style, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);
      control.Font = newFont;
      //oldFont.Dispose();
    }
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
      SetFonts(child);
  }
```

I thought it would keep resources down if I disposed of the old font after reassigning the control with the new one, but on closing the form I'm receiving access violation exceptions from one control type from a set of third party controls. 
If I comment out the line "oldFont.Dispose()" then I don't get the exception.

Is this a bug of the third party control set or is this to be expected?
Memory wise, can I get away with not explicitly disposing of the old font (The app runs on kiosks for 12hr+ a day) ?

Comment: If your telephone doesn't work then consider using a decompiler like Reflector or ILSpy to look at the 3rd party code.  See what its Font property setter does.

Comment: Good rule is to only dispose what you add. Did you add `oldFont`? No. Don't dispose it. Something else added it and will dispose it. You are only responsible for disposing `newFont` (when form is unloaded).

Comment: I decided to store the created fonts into a list as they were created and dispose of them at the end. But I got errors doing this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't dispose** of the old Font, that's the job of the Control whose font you're changing. Also, use tools such as GDIView to monitor your handles (such as fonts).

Comment: So far as I can tell, none of the built-in controls ever disposes of its associated `Font`, either when a new `Font` is set or when the control itself is destroyed.  Such fonts are simply abandoned, which will probably be fine if the number of fonts that get abandoned over the lifetime of a form is limited to the number of controls, but may be not-so-fine if many fonts are created and abandoned during the control's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Control fonts are very weird, as a consequence of the fact that a `Font` object actually encapsulates two different things:

1. Information about typeface, typestyle, etc.
2. A GDI font handle.

The latter aspect of a `Font` object encapsulates a resource; the former does not.  Calling `Dispose` on a `Font` object releases the latter, but does not destroy the former.

While I don't think I've seen their behavior "officially" documented anywhere, it seems that the built-in controls are never actually drawn using the `Font` object that was used to set the `Font` property; instead, they use the attributes of the assigned `Font` object to generate a new GDI font object and then use that to draw the control.  Although calling `Dispose` on a font object will make it unusable as an argument to `DrawString` or other such methods, it will not prevent its use as a "template" for making new font objects.

A consequence of this is that controls don't care if the assigned `Font` object is disposed (whether before or after it's assigned), nor do they ever dispose it.  Reading the `Font` property from a control will always return the same `Font` object that was last assigned to it, without regard for whether that `Font` object was disposed.  Consequently, it seems that if nothing will ever read a control's `Font` property and expect to draw with it, the safest way to assign a control's `Font` property without a temporary resource leak would be the very-bizarre-looking:

```
using f = new Font(...)
  theControl.Font = f;
```

That's arguably safer than reading the control's `Font` property and disposing that before assigning the new value, since the `using` approach above knows that the `Font` which is assigned to the control won't be used for anything else, while the latter approach can't know whether the same `Font` is used by some other code that would object to its disposal.

I really wish MS had documented how `Font` resources are supposed to be handled.  Unfortunately, so far as I know they haven't.

Comment: If you do this while the form or the control has not been shown yet (no handle created) then an 'ArgumentException' occurs when the control is shown. The exception is triggered in the ToLogFont method, started from 'System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback'... It will bring down your application. Tested with a Label and a TextBox

Comment: @Kabwla-TwoLips: Interesting.  The design of `Font` really seems to be a mess, IMHO, since it combines immutable state with resources.

Comment: what I do for many of these gdi types that may or may not need disposing is make my own type that only has the simple description (font name, size, and style). then I give it a `Use` method which wraps an action of `Font` in a `using` block. I have found this useful for at least `Pen`, `SolidBrush`, and especially `Font`.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to store the created fonts into a list as they were created and dispose of them during form.Dispose(). But on some windows I got errors doing this too.

What I've just realized is that the third party control must also be changing it's fonts during skinning/painting, so my font in the list was no longer valid for a control and may have been disposed by GC.

So storing the fonts for later disposal doesn't appear to be safe, and I wondered then if I should instead store controls that had had their fonts changed.

By this time the prospect of continuing along this line lost its attractiveness and instead I've manually gone through all 200+ forms in my app with search/replace instead lol

Im not very pleased.