# Should I dispose of an old font in the setter of a font property?

Tags: c#, fonts, dispose

I have a settings object for reports that has a number of Fonts in it.

They are defaulted like this

```
public Font TitleFont { get; set; } = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
```

but they can get changed in numerous places before being used for gdi+ rendering of reports.  This is not in a winForms control.

Fonts implement IDisposable so should I dispose of the old font in the setter for the property?  Or should I store the Fontname, size and style as 3 properties and only create the font when it's needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I dispose of the old font when changing the font of a control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103522/should-i-dispose-of-the-old-font-when-changing-the-font-of-a-control)

Comment: @Jens I don't think it's a duplicate, at least not of that one.  This is not a winforms control and my object has responsibility for the font

Comment: If it "has responsibility for the font" it should `Dispose` it. In case it just uses it (e.g if you've developed a helper class or a routine alike) it should not

Comment: @DmitryBychenko could you expand that into an answer? Should I not use automatic properties for Fonts?

Comment: @dibs487: As for automatic properties, it depends: in case the class is *responsible* for the font, you definitely should not; in case of *factory* you can, but I think, you should not as well: write-only property looks counter-inuitive; writing font *prototype* but reading *created* font crams two notions into a single property. As for helper class the automatic Font property looks quite well.

Comment: thanks @DmitryBychenko I'm still getting my head round your answer, but an automatic font property _with a default_ is definitely wrong right?

Comment: @dibs487: you're right: automatic font property with a default looks like wrong implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question here is if the class is *reponsible for the font*. 
When yes, it should `Dispose` the font:

```
 public class MyFontStorage: IDisposable {
   private Font m_MyFont; 
   ... 
   public Font MyFont {
     get {
       return m_MyFont; 
     } 
     set {
       if (m_MyFont == value)
         return;

       if (m_MyFont != null)
         m_MyFont.Dispose();

       m_MyFont = value;             
     }  
   }

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
     if (disposing) {
       MyFont = null;
     }
   }

   public void Dispose() {
     Dispose(this);

     GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
   } 
 }
```

....

```
 using (MyFontStorage storage = new MyFontStorage()) {
   ...
   // Storage is responsible for the font
   storage.MyFont = new Font(...);
   ...
   // Control has responsibility for the font as well, that's why
   // we have to create a copy in order to each font instance has one owner
   MyControl.Font = new Font(MyFontStorage.MyFont, MyFontStorage.Font.Style);  
   ... 
 }
```

Creating a *copy* instead of just assigning is a *bad practice* (prone to errors) and that's why you may want to implement a *factory* -

> "should I store the Fontname, size and style"

```
 public class MyFontFactory {
   private string m_FamilyName;
   private float m_Size;
   private FontStyle m_Style;

   ...

   public MyFontFactory(Font propotype) {
     ...
     m_FamilyName = propotype.FontFamily.Name;
     m_Size = propotype.Size;
     m_Style = propotype.Style;  
   } 

   public Font CreateFont() {
     return new Font(m_FamilyName, m_Size, m_Style);
   }
 }
```

....

```
 MyFontFactory factory = new factory(SomeControl.Font);
 ...  
 // Much more natural:
 // MyFontFactory creates a new font and MyControl takes responsibility for it
 MyControl.Font = factory.CreateFont();
```

Finally, in case of helper class / utility / routine etc.

```
 public class MyFontMisc {
   private Font m_MyFont;

   public Font MyFont {
     get {
       return m_MyFont; 
     } 
     set {
       m_MyFont = value;             
     }  
   }

   // Just some computations
   public float EmSizeInMillimeters {
     get {
       if (null == m_MyFont)
         return 0.0;

       ...
     }  
   }
 }
```

......

```
 // MyFontMisc doesn't hold any responsibility for the font  
 MyFontMisc misc = new MyFontMisc(SomeControl.Font); 

 // MyFontMisc just uses font for some computation and doesn't take 
 // any responsibility for the font (which owns to SomeControl) 
 Length = misc.EmSizeInMillimeters * 3.0f + 15.0f;
```